# returning object as json from mvc, how to display on the view

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, model-view-controller

I have list of objects which are returned from mvc controller as Json. I'm wondering how to display this objects on the view.

```
function GetTabData(xdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ('/Home/GetTabData'),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: xdata }),

        success: function (result) {
           /// what to do here? 
        },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
}

public JsonResult()
{
   ...
   var temp = getMyData...
   return Json(temp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
}
```

view page

```
<div id="showContent"> </div>
```

Comment: Could you post your controller logic for '/Home/GetTabData' action method?  Also when you say how should you display it, the answer really depends on how your data is structured and ultimately how you want to display it.

Comment: Could you just show an example of a such a JSON document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first step you have to do :

```
success: function (result) {
    /// what to do here? 
    result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    /// Exploit your object(s) ;)
},
```

Look here for more details on the exploitation : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I'm a bit confused since my list of objects is of some domain object type (complex object with images). Should I avoid using json in this case?

Comment: if the image is just a link, no problem<br />
if the image is under its byte code, i think you cannot exploit it with javascript ...

Comment: object have stored only image path so it is a string. Any idea how to parse custom object, for simplicity CustomObject with properties string  Name and Age int ?

Comment: Yes, just after `result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);` try `alert(result[0].Name)` if you returned an array, or try `alert(result.Name)` if you have only one object.